# How To Fix Rails Migration Generator Timestamp Clock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timestamp, timezone, migration

It's currently 21:48 (9:48pm) on October 9th. I just generated a migration using "rails generate migration" and the migration it created was given the timestamp prefix 20191010014453 which equates to 2019-10-10 01:44:53. It should be 2019-10-09 21:48:54. My system time is correct (21:48) and when I open a Rails console and type Time.now it returns "2019-10-09 21:48:54 -0400" so the Rails console is using the correct local system time.

What clock is the rails generator using and how can I set it to my local time?